# Base 2 exponential of native int

Tags: native, dafny

Some algorithms (allocate a binary tree...) need to compute a base 2 exponential. How to compute it for this native type?

```
newtype {:nativeType "uint"} u32 =
  x: nat | 0 <= x < 2147483648
```

This is an obvious try:

```
function pow2(n: u32): (r: u32)
  requires n < 10
{
  if n == 0 then 1 else 2 * pow2(n - 1)
}
```

It fails because Dafny doubts that the product stays below `u32`'s max value. How to prove that it's value is below 2**10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it is more convenient to first define the unbounded version of the function, and then prove a lemma showing that when `n < 10` (or `n < 32`, even) it is in bounds.

```
function pow2(n: nat): int
{
  if n == 0 then 1 else 2 * pow2(n - 1)
}

lemma pow2Bounds(n: nat)
    requires n < 32
    ensures 0 <= pow2(n) < 0x100000000
{ /* omitted here; two proofs given below */ }

function pow2u32(n: u32): u32
    requires n < 32
{
    pow2Bounds(n as nat);
    pow2(n as nat) as u32
}
```

Intuitively, we might expect the lemma to go through automatically, because there are only a small number of cases to consider: `n = 0`, `n = 1`, ... `n = 31`. But Dafny will not perform such case analysis automatically. Instead, we have a couple of options.

### First proof

First, we can prove a more general property, which, by the magic of inductive reasoning, is *easier* to prove, despite being stronger than what we need.

```
lemma pow2Monotone(a: nat, b: nat)
    requires a < b
    ensures pow2(a) < pow2(b)
{}  // Dafny is able to prove this automatically by induction.
```

The lemma then follows.

```
lemma pow2Bounds(n: nat)
    requires n < 32
    ensures 0 <= pow2(n) < 0x100000000
{
    pow2Monotone(n, 32);
}
```

### Second proof

Another way to prove it is to tell Dafny it should unroll `pow2` up to 32 times, using a `:fuel` attribute. These 32 unrollings are essentially the same as asking Dafny to do case analysis on each possible value. Dafny can then complete the proof without additional help.

```
lemma {:fuel pow2,31,32} pow2Bounds(n: nat)
    requires n < 32
    ensures 0 <= pow2(n) < 0x100000000
{}
```

The `:fuel` attribute is (lightly) documented in the [Dafny Reference Manual](https://github.com/Microsoft/dafny/blob/master/Docs/DafnyRef/out/DafnyRef.pdf) in Section 24.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a cheat, but with so narrow a domain, this works very well.

```
const pow2: seq<u32> :=
  [0x1, 0x2, 0x4, 0x8, 0x10, 0x20];

lemma pow2_exponential(n: u32)
  ensures n == 0    ==> pow2[n] == 1
  ensures 0 < n < 6 ==> pow2[n] == 2 * pow2[n - 1]  
{}
```